# Eclipse stops running

Tags: eclipse, performance

Whenever I try to use decrement in wrong way Eclipse stops working. Seems it started to happen after I installed Lombok. The code is shown below:

```java
public class Patterns {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pattern31(5);
    }

    static void pattern31(int n) {
        n = 5;
        
        for (int row = 1 ; row <= n; row++) {
            int columns = row>n ? 2*n-row:row;
            int space=n-columns;
            int p='A';
            for(int s=0; s<=space; s++) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            for(int col=1; col<columns; col++) {
                System.out.print((char) p++ +" ");
            }
            for(int col=2; col<=columns; col--) {
                System.out.print((char) p++ +" ");
            }
            
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I also have this message in the log:

!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\User'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

Comment: In what way does it "Stop working"? Does it crash? Or is your program running and eclipse starts behaving slowly? I ran your code and it's an endless loop (the last loop will never finish) which makes eclipse slow as it tries to print all the things onto console. Fix your code. But yes, eclipse should have better support for weird and super-long outputs in the console, you can file a performance bug if there isn't one already. It's not going to be a high priority, though.

Comment: Your code  runs forever, because the `col--` means the second loop never stops (probably should be col++). Eclipse is struggling to deal with the vast amount of output the looping code is producing.

Comment: (Also, one thing that trips beginners is that an infinite program is still running on your background and you need to terminate it manually. In Eclipse, there is a Terminate (red square) button in the Console view).